# Deadlock while using goroutines

Tags: go, concurrency, channel, goroutine

I have a program which does 2 things:

- Read log entries and create `logEntry` objects
- Process each `logEntry` instances

Here, reading is done by separate goroutines and processing of all the read entries is done by a single goroutine.

I'm using a waitgroup - `wg` to ensure that all the log entries are read before the program quits and a signal channel - `done` to ensure the processing of the log entries are completed.

The waitgroup is working as expected, however when I call `<-done` to ensure that the program exits only after the read log files are processed, it throws the error `fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!`.

Could someone please explain why this is happening and how to fix the above error?

main.go:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type logEntry struct {
    lines      []string
    created_at string
    line_count int
}

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func main() {
    linesChan := make(chan (logEntry))

    done := make(chan (bool), 1)

    // Process entries from lines
    go func() {
        for c := range linesChan {
            time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
            fmt.Printf("%v\n", c)
        }

        done <- true
    }()

    // Read lines
    for i := 1; i <= 10; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(i int, linesChan chan (logEntry)) {
            read(i, linesChan)
        }(i, linesChan)
    }

    // Wait till all the files are read
    wg.Wait()

    // Wait till all the log entries are processed
    <-done
    close(done)
}

func read(count int, channel chan (logEntry)) {
    fmt.Println(count, "read")
    channel <- logEntry{
        line_count: count,
    }
    wg.Done()
}
```

Output:

```
10 read
6 read
3 read
1 read
4 read
8 read
7 read
2 read
5 read
9 read
{[]  10}
{[]  6}
{[]  3}
{[]  1}
{[]  4}
{[]  8}
{[]  7}
{[]  2}
{[]  5}
{[]  9}
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan receive]:
main.main()
  .../main.go:44 +0x13a

goroutine 18 [chan receive]:
main.main.func1()
  .../main.go:24 +0x145
created by main.main
  .../main.go:23 +0x9d
exit status 2
```

Comment: You never close `linesChan`, so you will never receive from `done`

Comment: Aside from the fix @JimB noted, your workers are not being used very efficiently. They only read one record from the channel and then exit. So your 10 goroutines read just 10 `logEntry` combined. This may or may not be what you want. Typically a worker will `range` over the input channel so it is fully utilized.

Comment: @JimB This worked, I closed `linesChan` after the waitgroup and it worked as expected. Thanks!

Comment: @colm.anseo I'm trying to read a large data file and create log entries from the same. Here, `create` would be changed to read the file in batches and `process` would be to create the log entries from the read batches.

I had stripped down the code to the one above, since adding the rest seems irrelevant to the problem at hands. Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your case you are listening for `linesChan`, but not close it. You need to close this channel, when all data will be passed. `done <- true` won't be executed.

But don't need channel for sync here, `sync.WaitGroup{}` will be enough.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type logEntry struct {
    lines      []string
    created_at string
    line_count int
}

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func main() {
    linesChan := make(chan (logEntry))

    // Process entries from lines
    go func() {
        for c := range linesChan {
            time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
            fmt.Printf("%v\n", c)
        }
    }()

    // Read lines
    for i := 1; i <= 10; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(i int, linesChan chan (logEntry)) {
            read(i, linesChan)
        }(i, linesChan)
    }

    // Wait till all the files are read
    wg.Wait()
}

func read(count int, channel chan (logEntry)) {
    fmt.Println(count, "read")
    channel <- logEntry{
        line_count: count,
    }
    wg.Done()
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I did to correct this. One more thing to notice here is that after `wg.Wait()`, we'd also need to close the `linesChan`, otherwise the for loop throws an error since it goes on infinitely.